# Retrieving results of an IEnumerable result value

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of records in a variable. I need to retrieve the list of variables from an IEnumerable, as well as iterate to each record and get the value either with a for-each loop or a for loop. When I try to view this in quick watch, I am able to view the result view.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Welcome to SO. It is expected to have done some of your own research before posing a question, and to include a code sample when you do. Pleas read the FAQ for more information.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something simple as below:

```
foreach(var record in records)
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your post is a little difficult to understand but perhaps...

```
records.Select(r => r.PropertyWithValueYouWant).ToList();
```